# Keyboard shortcut to switch windows

Tags: scheme, keyboard-shortcuts, racket

I am using `drscheme` or `drracket` for `scheme`. I have found [this](http://download.plt-scheme.org/doc/4.1.4/html/drscheme/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) and [this](http://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html) for their keyboard shortcuts, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> does not seem to work...

How to switch the cursor between the two windows/editors: definition and interaction?

Comment: What environment are you using?  Windows, Mac, or Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're using Windows, Control + F6 key should work; but you can check the current keybindings by going to the 'Edit' menu, choose 'Keybindings' near the bottom, and then select the 'Show Active Keybindings' item. Then, search for "shift-focus" -- it should show you the keyboard shortcut as it is set up on your system. (If you're using Mac OS, Alt+tab  and/or  Control+x and then o  should work.)